# When I take screenshot, How to remove the button?

Tags: iphone

When I take screenshot, How to remove the button? I am using this code for screen shot

```
CGImageRef originalImage = UIGetScreenImage();
CGImageRef videoImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(originalImage, CGRectMake(0, 66, 320, 230));            
UIImage *snapShotImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:videoImage];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(snapShotImage, nil, nil, nil);
CGImageRelease(originalImage);                
CGImageRelease(videoImage);
```

[image]

Comment: simple.. onclick hide your button .. then execute your this code..

Comment: if button hide not working for you then try to Crop your Photo.

Answer (score 1):

remove your button just before taking the screen shots, you can store its frame in CGRect and add it again after **UIGraphicsEndImageContext();** line

```
 CGRect rect = yourButton.frame; // store your buttons frame
[yourButton removeFromSuperView];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

yourButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[yourButton setFrame:rect];
[yourButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourButtonImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(yourButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view yourButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

If the button image is included in the other image this could get really complicated (then I would recommend you to enter fullscreen and take the screenshot).

If the button image isn't included directly in the other image (eg. just a HTML overlay) than you could also easy hide it with css.

But perhaps there are better ways than making screenshots in iOS…

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can make a view like backView and then on button click call this code....

```
-(IBAction)screenShotBtnPress :(id)sender  
{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.window.frame.size);
    [BackView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

This code take the screenShot of BackView, make IBOutlet for this view and then connect this....

Answer (score -2):

Hide that button before taking the screenshot.